# Who is Angel's mother?

Tags: borderlands-series

I played the 'snap' out of the Borderlands series and really know much about the games. But after the [Pre-Sequel](http://store.steampowered.com/app/261640/), I still have one big question: Who is Angel's mother? Since we only know about one girlfriend Handsome Jack (who is Angel's father) had, [Mad Moxxi](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Mad_Moxxi), I'd say that she is Angel's mother but that would not make much sense to me.

Does anyone know more about this question or has anyone encountered some ECHO recorders, that could enlighten me?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to the [Borderlands Wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Angel#Background), Angel's mother is unidentified.

> Angel is the daughter of Hyperion programmer Handsome Jack. The identity of her mother remains unknown, but her absence from Angel's life is reportedly a result of Angel's Siren powers.

Answer (score 1):

Could be Steele. She was also a siren and Angel basically lured steele into opening the vault first to be killed by the destroyer. could be what Jack means by "you didn't see what she did to her mother.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you have any sources to support your theory or is it just something you came to on your own?

Answer (score 0):

Good points but in the Arid Nexus Handsome Jack says "You didn't see what she did to her mother," implying she is either dead or has sustained a distinct injury, such as Zaragoza who knows his name and also looks messed up.

Answer (score -1):

Angel was there before Nisha came into play. In the first Borderlands, Jack never met Nisha and Angel was guiding the players at that time. In the Pre-Sequel, Jack uses angel to get info on the 4 playable characters to see if they would make for reliable mercenaries.

Answer (score -2):

Well we do know that Nisha was also one of Jack's girlfriends. She also has black hair like Angel.

Comment: Got any credible sources?

Comment: Given evidence revealed in the pre-squeal, we can rule out Nisha as Angel's mother. Jack first meets Nisha during the events of the pre-squeal; Jack also has a picture of a young (around 3-6 years old) Angel on his desk, so Angel would have been born before Jack ever met Nisha.